# Need a advanced event calendar for a none WordPress project

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I need a advanced event calendar in jQuery like the WordPress plugin in the link.

[WordPress calendar plugin demo](http://wordpressbooking.systems/example/with-hours-intervals/)

I need the same item in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) for that. Works very nice and should work for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for the link but i need an advance event calendar like the link below   http://wordpressbooking.systems/example/with-hours-intervals  unfortunately its for word press i need the same item in jqery if you know please help me i am looking for that

Comment: please check the link        http://wordpressbooking.systems/example/with-hours-intervals/

Comment: Whats advanced for you if this isnt?

Comment: please see the link below : http://wordpressbooking.systems/example/with-hours-intervals/

Comment: This is a word press plugin and i am not working on a word press project the client need the same event calendar(functions) i guess its created in  jquery . if you know any similar event calendar like this  please replay I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for more possibilites, you could also use http://codecanyon.net/item/booking-calendar-pro-jquery-plugin/244645 - [here](http://codecanyon.net/item/booking-calendar-pro-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/244645) you can also see a demo of it.

This is actually equal to your plugin, just written for "normal JQuery".

Comment: ya i got it thanks can we have any free version like below : http://www.checkingarea.com/BOOKING/

Comment: Well I don't know about a free version of that plugin, but as you asked for a plugin similar to your worpress plugin (costs of 50$), then the 7$ should be no problem, is it?

Comment: ya you are right looking forward  to buying this waiting for the client replay  thanks in advance